# joining a count on a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: comments & blog

blog has the following fields: id(Unique key),title, author, body, date, img, imgdes, tags

comments : key(Unique key), postid(related to the id of blog),name, email, date, message

Im trying to display all of my blog post and the number of comments on every post.

So im trying to "count(postid) where postid=id"

I got something to work but its based around having 1 comment which wont work but this is it:

```
 SELECT a.postid,c.author,c.title, c.id,c.body,c.date,c.pic, c.tags, c.imgdesc,  
 COUNT(*) AS num_comments FROM comments a LEFT JOIN blog c ON c.id = a.postid 
 GROUP BY c.id order by id DESC"
```

Again this only work when everything has a comment and i get why but i cant figure out how to implement what I want.

To put it all out there i have:

```
 $sql="***( help 1 of 2) what to set the query to****"
 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  <?php do{ ?>
  <html stuff here>
  <?php echo $blog['title']?><br>
  <?php echo $blog['*******(help 2 of 2) # of comments display here******']
  <?php } while($blog = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));?>
```

im sure this is a easy join but i have no clue thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query it may works for you

```
SELECT a.postid,c.author,c.title, c.id,c.body,c.date,c.pic, c.tags, c.imgdesc, COUNT(a.key) AS num_comments FROM blog c left outer join comments a ON a.postid = c.id GROUP BY c.id order by id DESC
```

Comment: mind explaining? works as i requested thanks for reading the question

Comment: read left join working in mysql you can understand then. also rated ans as upvote if it works :).

Answer (score 1):

if you want all the blog posts then it should be on the left side of the left join.

Comment: Im very bad at joins example of how to work the count in if I move it around?

Comment: "I got something to work but its based around having 1 comment which wont work". You had this problem as comments table was on the right side of the left join. Left join works as follows: it maps each record on left table with a matching record on the right table and it still displays the records in the left table for which there was no matched record. If you have comment table on the left, then even if there is no comment on a blog it will still be displayed with count as zero

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies where you write: `FROM comments a LEFT JOIN blog c ON c.id = a.postid 
 GROUP BY c.id order by id DESC"`

The `comments a` and `blog c` don't seem to be correct references.

Should it be `FROM comments.a LEFT JOIN blog.c ON` ...?

Comment: No this query works as it suppose too Im trying to make a new query that can count the postid where it's like blog.Id and add this number to the table with a join

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count the number of comments in each blog? if yes then,
`SELECT c.postid,count(key) as num_of_comments
FROM blog b, comments c
WHERE b.id = c.postid
GROUP BY c.postid`

Another easy way out:
As you have the postid as a foreign key, you can just get the results from comments table
`SELECT postid,count(key) as num_of_comments
FROM comments
GROUP BY postid`